# Rotation map by an irrational on $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

$$\newcommand{\ob}{\operatorname{orbit}}
$$
Let $S^1=[0,1)~~mod~~1$. Let $0<\alpha<1$ be an irrational and let $\tau$ be the rotation by $\alpha$ and $\beta \in \ob(\alpha)$. Is it true that if $0\leq x<\tau^{-m}(\beta)<x'<\beta$ then $0<\tau^m(x)<\beta<\tau^m(x')<1$ for all $\beta \in \ob(\alpha)$ or some $\beta \in \ob(\alpha)$.  I tried to do one part by taking $\beta=n\alpha-[n\alpha]$, where $[]$ is the greatest integer function, but finally I am getting as $0<\tau^m(x)<\beta+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orbit of $\alpha$ is dense due to its irrationality. Thus you can easily choose $m>0$ and $\beta$ from the orbit of $\alpha$ such that $0<\tau^{-m}(\beta)<\beta<1/2 \mod 1$. We get the second train of inequalities from the first one by rotating all the considered points by $0< m\alpha \leq 1/2 \mod 1$. The inequalities are preserved because $\beta+m\alpha<1/2+1/2=1$; this is all nicely visible when drawn on the circle. So it is definitely true for some $\beta$ (independently from whether it is from the orbit of $\alpha$ or not).
But it is not true for every $\beta$ from the orbit of $\alpha$. Just contemplate the situation when $\beta-\tau^{-m}(\beta)>1/2$.

To the original problem - one can show, in fact, more:
For any $\beta \in (0,1)$ and any $x,x' \in \mathbb S^1$ there is $m \geq 0$ such that $\tau^m(x) \in [0,\beta]$ and $\tau^m(x') \in (\beta,1)$.
One way how to see this is the following. Thanks to irrationality of $\alpha$ we know that some iterate of $\tau$ is a rotation by a "really small angle". For our purposes this means that for arbitrary fixed $x<x' \in \mathbb S^1$, we take $n>0$ such that $\tau^n =$ rotation by $\gamma$ with $0<\gamma<\min\{\beta,1-\beta,x'-x\}$.
Now, take any $k \geq 0$ such that $\tau^k(x) \in [0,\beta]$ and $\tau^k(x)<\tau^k(x')$ (again, this is possible due to irrationality of $\alpha$). If $\tau^k(x') \in (\beta,1)$, we're done. If not, look at $\tau^{k+n}(x)$ and $\tau^{k+n}(x')$, $\tau^{k+2n}(x)$ and $\tau^{k+2n}(x')$, etc. until the first ocurrence of $\tau^{k+ln}(x') \in (\beta,1)$. Because of how $\gamma$ was chosen, $\tau^{k+ln}(x') \in [0,\beta]$. Obviously, $m=k+ln$ solves the problem.
(I switch between the circle and the interval relatively freely hoping that it doesn't cause misunderstandings.)

Comment: First choose a $\beta \in [0,\frac{1}{2})$ by denseness of orbit of $\alpha$.  Now let $x,x' \in [0,\beta]$ such that $0 \leq x<x'<\beta$. Then by denseness we can find an $m$ such that $0\leq x <\tau^{-m}(\beta)<x'$.  Then can I conclude that $0<\tau^m(x)<\beta<\tau^m(x')<1$? But wht $\beta+m\alpha<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: $\tau^{-m}$ is the inverse to the rotation by $m\alpha$. So we rotate the first picture by $m\alpha$ to get the second picture - we simply have to add to every member of the first train of inequalities $m\alpha$ to get the second one. And the first one is contained in $[0,1/2)$ thus the second one is contained in $[m\alpha,1/2+m\alpha)$. The problem might appear only if we have to "break" the interval during the rotation because of modulo 1 which we avoided by choosing $\beta<1/2$.

Comment: I have to prove that for a suitable $\beta \in ~~Orbit(\alpha)$, the function $\phi=1_{[0,\beta]}-\beta$ on $S^1$ have the following property. Given $x\neq x' \in [0,1)$, there exists $m$ such that $\phi(\tau^m(x))\neq \phi(\tau^m(x'))$. If $x \in [0,\beta]$and $x' \in (\beta,1)$  or vice versa we can take $m$ to be zero. What happens if both $x,x' \in [0,\beta]$ or in $(\beta,1)$.

Comment: Choose $\beta <\frac{1}{2}$ as above and this settles if $x,x' \in [0,\beta]$. What happens if $\beta<x<x'<1$. Here also there exists $m>0$ such that $\beta<x<\tau^{-m}(\beta)<x'<1$. Can I conclude that $\tau^m(x)< \beta<\tau^m(x')$?

Comment: I address the original problem in the edit of the answer.

Comment: i will go through the answer and i will ask incase of any doubts.

Comment: The correspondence between [0,1) and $S^1$ is $x \mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$ and as $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$ the circle is tracked counterclockwise once. Am I right?

Comment: We can find an $\gamma=n\alpha$ for $0< \gamma<~min~\{\beta,1-\beta,x'-x\}$ since $\alpha$ is irrational Orbit of $\alpha$ will be dense. Similarly orbit of any element is dense . So for $x$, we can find $k$ such that $0< \tau^k(x)<\beta$. But why does $\tau^k(x)<\tau^k(x')$ hold?

Comment: The correspondence via the exp function is correct. About the question above: $0< \tau^k(x)<\beta$ truly doesn't automatically imply $\tau^k(x)<\tau^k(x')$ - one has to choose $k$ wrt to both conditions but this surely can be done. Just aim for $\tau^k(x)>0$ to be close enough to $0$, ie. closer than $x-x'$. What is also implicitly used here is the fact that the rotation of the circle is an isometry, ie. it preserves the distance of the preimages to the images. I guess all this might appear a bit messy contrary to the clear geometric picture when you imagine what 's really going on the circle.

Comment: Let $y=\tau^k(x)$. By the choice of $k$, $y<\beta$. Now $\tau^n$ is rotation by $\gamma$ where we have done the choice of $\gamma$. Now $\tau^{nl+k}(x)=\tau^{nl}(y)=y+l\gamma~mod~1$.  Will it be less than $\beta$ even if $l$ is large?

Comment: Not necessarily. But it will be less then $\beta$ when $\tau^{nl+k}(x')$ exceeds $\beta$ for the first time thanks to $\gamma<x'-x$. Just imagine a pair of points $x, x'$ moving simultaneously along the circle by small steps $\gamma$.

Comment: I could understand it pictorially. Problem is in proving it in rigorously by algebraic expressions.

Comment: We start with two points $y:=\tau^k(x) < y':=\tau^k(x')$ in $[0,\beta]$ and we move them both by $\gamma$ in each step. Obviously, after a finitely many steps, the bigger one enters $(\beta,1)$ for the first time (it cannot jump over it due to $\gamma<1-\beta$). Now use $\gamma<x'-x$ to show that the smaller one is still in $[0,\beta]$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I could understand it fully. Really thanks for the great help.

Comment: As $\tau$ is an isometry distance between $y-y'$=$x-x'$ right?

Comment: You're welcome. This type of reasoning might get easily much less clear than the geometric picture behind it - it's because of that modulo 1. There might be a nicer way to show it perhaps.

Comment: Yes, it's an isometry on the circle as every rotation. But be careful with what distance we use - commonly on the circle we take the lengths of the shortest arc between the points (normalized to get 1 as the circumference, say). To avoid some unnecessary complications, I assumed $x<x'$ but one can drop it (and does more cases, if one wants to be rigorous).